# How to modify array of dictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` with several `NSDictionaries`.  I want to create a new `NSArray` with the same number of `NSDictionaries` but I only want some keys in the dictionary, not all of the ones.

Example:

Array has 2 dictionaries.  Each dictionary has key `name, age, address, email, phone`.

I want new array that also has the 2 dictionaries, but only the `name and address` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *replacementArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[existingArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
    ^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
         NSDictionary *newDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"], @"name", [dictionary objectForKey:@"address"], @"address", nil];
         [replacementArray addObject:newDictionary];
    }
];
```

Comment: Error says missing sentenial in method dispatch.

Comment: When I first posted my answer I was missing a `nil` at the end of the arguments for `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`, but I put it in like 30 seconds later. That should be the problem, assuming you got the code before I fixed it.

Comment: Actually I need to add this in the block right? `dictionary = [aSkus objectAtIndex:idx];`

Comment: No, dictionary already gets set to [aSkus objectAtIndex:idx] at each iteration of the enumeration, so you should be fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (compatible with iOS 2+):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *origDict in origArray) { // Replace origArray with your array's name
    [newArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[origDict objectForKey@"name"], @"name", [origDict objectForKey@"address"], @"address", nil]];
}
NSArray *newImmutableArray = [newArray copy] // If you want to ensure your array is not mutable
// ...
[newImmutableArray release]; // To balance -copy above
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for(i=0;i<[firstArray count];i++){

 NSArray *objectArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[firstArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"],[[firstArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"address"]];

 NSArray *keyArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"address"];
 NSDictionary *myDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objectArray forKeys:keyArray];

 [secondArray addObject:myDictionary];
}
```